# Parse Datetime string in local date format in javascript (preferably using luxon)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, luxon

Suppose I have a datetime string `10/09/2019 10:03:00.000 AM`.

Now, if I am in USA, I'll read it as 9th October 2019 and if I am in India, I'll read it as 10th September 2019.

So, my question is how do I parse this string as a Date object in such a way that it is parsed based on the local timezone.

I am using `luxon`, but, pure javascript solution will also work.

Comment: What you're describing isn't really related to timezones; it's date format preference based on culture, `day/month/year` vs `month/day/year`. If you want that handled properly, you'll likely have to allow your users to set their date format preference, but hopefully for display only. Most systems expect dates/timestamps to be handled in `year-month-day hour:minute:second`, with or without timezone (+/- offset) included.

Comment: Did you read the luxon documentation?  https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/parsing.html#fromformat

Comment: `fromFormat` expects a format to be provided. I want automatic parsing based on culture. I guess as Tim suggested, I need to switch to `year-month-day hour:minute:second`

Comment: So your real question is "how do I tell what format the user expects". You can't, so present timestamps in an unambiguous format, and tell the user the format you expect when requesting input.

Answer (score 14):

Using a recent version of Luxon that supports the use of "macro" tokens in the parser:

```
> DateTime.fromFormat("10/09/2019 10:03:00.000 AM", "D hh:mm:ss.SSS a").toISO()
'2019-10-09T10:03:00.000-04:00'
> DateTime.fromFormat("10/09/2019 10:03:00.000 AM", "D hh:mm:ss.SSS a", { locale: "en-IN" }).toISO()
'2019-09-10T10:03:00.000-04:00'
```

IMO, this solution is brittle, in the sense that Luxon's parser here very strict, essentially requiring that the date part match *exactly* `DateTime.toFormat` in that locale, so differences in 0-padding, slashes vs hyphens, etc.

Comment: I upvoted it, because I found the format of the second argument here

Comment: Also note: The 'F' token is great for this format: `DateTime.fromFormat("10/09/2019 10:03:00.000 AM", "F")`.